# asp.net after publishing error "The page you have requested has either been moved or is no longer available"

Tags: c#, asp.net, publishing

I am publishing my ASP.NET web site to the server using web deploy method. I validated the connection and published it, everything works fine till this point!

But when I try to run the website through URL on the browser, It gives me error that -

> LOGO
>
> The page you have requested has either been moved or is no longer
>   available. Please use our web site's search feature to find the page
>   you are looking for or contact us for more information.

But when I checked my files on the server, the files are there. Can someone suggest me what can be the possible reason for this error despite that files are present on the server.

Comment: Do you have a default page configured, or are you just going to the web root?
Can you navigate to a specific page?
Do you have access to the servers Web Server log files?

Comment: Yes I do have a default page that is redirecting to other page, but its not displaying as well. I tried default as well as specific page.

Comment: No, I donot have access to Web Server log files

Comment: Its difficult to help more without knowing more. Does your hosting provider support webdeploy? Was the site visible on the sever before you did the deployment, or is this the first time it has been deployed. Have you just set the DNS up (i.e. are you still waiting for it to propogte?)

Comment: Actually, I have published similar projects before as well. It always worked fine! Its the first time for me as well, I am having this issue.

Comment: I found other detail if it can help, I added simple html form in project and publish it, It works and is shown. But, when I add simple asp.net web form with no code, it is not shown and gives the error. @Matt

Comment: Who is the host? It maybe that they have not enabled .net support and so the web server does not know about aspx files. (Though I would expect a different error if so).
Is the html form in the same folder as the aspx files?

Comment: Yes html file was in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the issue:

1. At first, I turned customError mode Off to view detailed errors. That helped me!!
2. I had an error in one of my dll files. Actually, my computer was using excel dll version 15 and server computer was not compatible with version 15 as it was using office 2007.

I installed dll file that is compatible with server and removed the references for version 15. AND it worked!!!